# Python Pandas compare date columns, check if not empty, conditional > <= logic, return value

Tags: python, pandas

using Python3 Pandas, I'm trying to calculate RESULT. I keep getting Boolean ambiguous value errors. Do I need to test that each date column I compare with is not null first to avoid an error? The end result should mimic:

```
#check if D3_UNTIL is not empty
if df.RUNNING_DATE.isna()==False:
    if df.D3_UNTIL.isna()==False:
        if.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D3_UNTIL:
            df.RESULT = df.DVAL3
        elif (df.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D2_UNTIL & df.RUNNING_DATE < df.D3_UNTIL):
            df.RESULT = df.DVAL2    
        elif (df.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D1_UNTIL & df.RUNNING_DATE < df.D2_UNTIL):
            df.RESULT = df.DVAL1
        else None
#check if D2.UNTIL is not empty
    elif df.D2_UNTIL.isna()==False:
        if.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D2_UNTIL:
            df.RESULT = df.DVAL2
        elif (df.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D1_UNTIL & df.RUNNING_DATE < df.D2_UNTIL):
            df.RESULT = df.DVAL1    
        else None
#check if D1.UNTIL is not empty    
    elif df.D1_UNTIL.isna()==False:
        if.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D1_UNTIL:
            df.RESULT = df.DVAL1
        else None
else None



RUNNING_DATE  D1_UNTIL  DVAL1  D2_UNTIL  DVAL2  D3_UNTIL  DVAL3  RESULT
1/1/2018      1/1/2018  10                                       10             
1/2/2018                                
1/3/2018      1/1/2018                          
1/4/2018      1/1/2018  10     1/3/2018  15             
1/5/2018      1/1/2018  10     1/3/2018  20     1/31/2018 100    20 
1/6/2018      1/1/2018  10               999                
1/7/2018      1/1/2018  10     1/4/2018  25     1/6/2018  300    300
```

Comment: Can you run `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` and paste the output somewhere in your question so it is easy to reproduce your data?

Comment: The nature of ambiguous error is this.  You have a series, s, of data some True and some False.   What should you return if s == True?  Some of your data is True and some of that data is False.  One way to get around this is (s == True).any() or (s == True).all(), hence you clearly define if any value is True return True or respectively, if all values in s are True then return True.

Comment: So line 2 in example code df.RUNNING_DATE.isna() == False, well, what if some values in df.RUNNING_DATE are null and some aren't, then the if statement is ambiguous.

Comment: Your result is inconsistent with your logic. The first row should be assigned `DVAL1`, as should the row for `1/6/2018`

Comment: @ALollz Yes, good catch. I was typing it and forgot to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With if-else statements you can use `np.select` to implement your logic. Also checking `df.RUNNING_DATE.isna()==False` is superfluous; just use `df.RUNNING_DATE.notnull()`.

Further, the logic here can be simplified **immensely**.

- Any `>=`, `==`, or `<=`   date comparison with `NaT` will return
  `False`, so first checking if the value is finite not needed when already checking if RUNNING_DATE is greater. Also any comparison of `NaT` with `NaT` returns `False`, giving us a default check if RUNNING_DATE is null.
- Since your date checks span the entire range of possibilities, just check `>=` sequentially.

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy a np

# Ensure Datetime
#df['RUNNING_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.RUNNING_DATE, errors='coerce')
#df['D1_UNTIL'] = pd.to_datetime(df.D1_UNTIL, errors='coerce')
#df['D2_UNTIL'] = pd.to_datetime(df.D2_UNTIL, errors='coerce')
#df['D3_UNTIL'] = pd.to_datetime(df.D3_UNTIL, errors='coerce')

conds = [
    df.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D3_UNTIL,
    df.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D2_UNTIL,
    df.RUNNING_DATE >= df.D1_UNTIL]

choices = [
    df.DVAL3,
    df.DVAL2,
    df.DVAL1]

df['RESULT'] = np.select(conds, choices, default=None)
```

#### Output:

(I added extra rows at the end to illustrate logic)

```
  RUNNING_DATE   D1_UNTIL  DVAL1   D2_UNTIL  DVAL2   D3_UNTIL  DVAL3 RESULT
0   2018-01-01 2018-01-01   10.0        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN     10
1   2018-01-02        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN   None
2   2018-01-03 2018-01-01    NaN        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN    NaN
3   2018-01-04 2018-01-01   10.0 2018-01-03   15.0        NaT    NaN     15
4   2018-01-05 2018-01-01   10.0 2018-01-03   20.0 2018-01-31  100.0     20
5   2018-01-06 2018-01-01   10.0        NaT  999.0        NaT    NaN     10
6   2018-01-07 2018-01-01   10.0 2018-01-04   25.0 2018-01-06  300.0    300
7          NaT        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN   None
8          NaT        NaT    NaN 2018-01-01   24.0        NaT    NaN   None
```

Comment: For my full understanding, in conds list variable and choices list variable, does np.select evaluate each for it's element position within the list (i.e. if cond[0] then choices[0], elif cond[1] then choices[1], ....

Comment: @Chris, Yes, exactly. And from the documentation `When multiple conditions are satisfied, the first one encountered in condlist is used`, which is why we are safely able to check the conditions as greater than in that specific order. In the case that none of them are satisfied (which is the case when `RUNNING_DATE` is null, or when running date is less than all of the other fields, it will use the default, which we set to `None`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a great help and is much more elegant than what I was approaching.

Comment: @Chris Glad it helped! You were taking a more row by row approach, and typically with pandas you can approach these calculations as one which acts on the entire set of columns, which is where `np.select` comes in.